# VS 2017 Enable native code debugging x64 - ntdll.dll exception

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2017, unmanaged

In Visual Studio 2017 x64, when I "Enable native code debugging" in Project->Properties->Debug I get the following exception when staring debug.  It works fine in VS2015 x64 * x86 but only works in x86 for VS2017. Does someone know how to get around this or confirm it is a VS2017 x64 issue.

[image: Exception]

Unhandled esception at ... (ntdll.dll) in DebugAPI.exe

Steps to recreate.

1. New c# Console Application .net framework
2. Set Properties->Build->Platform Target = x64
3. Set Properties->Debug->Enable native code debugging = checked
4. Set Debug->Options->Debugging->Symbols->Microsoft Symbol Servers = checked
5. Start debug

Comment: My app works with VS 2015 but I'm having this problem with VS 2017 and VS 2019. If I launch the app without the debugger and then attach the debugger it works.

Comment: How did you solve this? I have the same problem with VS 2019. My project is set as Debug and x64 platform.